# How to sanitize strings for storage in a sqlite database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sanitization

I'm trying to store tags from mp3's in a sqlite database and I get the following error:

```
 
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "songs" ("album", "artist", "created_at", "length", "path", "store_id", "title", "track_number", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["album", "\xFF\xFE2\x001\x00"], ["artist", "\xFF\xFEa\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00e\x00"], ["created_at", Tue, 24 Jul 2012 03:34:03 UTC +00:00], ["length", 15], ["path", "/audios/music/Adele - Discography (Complete) [2008 - 2011]/Adele - 21 [2011] + Bonus Tracks/01. Adele - Rolling in the Deep.mp3"], ["store_id", 3], ["title", "\xFF\xFEr\x00o\x00l\x00l\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00e\x00e\x00p\x00"], ["track_number", "01"], ["updated_at", Tue, 24 Jul 2012 03:34:03 UTC +00:00]]
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8: INSERT INTO "songs" ("album", "artist", "created_at", "length", "path", "store_id", "title", "track_number", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8: INSERT INTO "songs" ("album", "artist", "created_at", "length", "path", "store_id", "title", "track_number", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How could I strip or sanitize the input?

Comment: are input data really looks like '\xFF\xFE2\x001\x00'?

Comment: The data is automatically generated from id3 tags, most programs seem to strip those characters, others display them as empty boxes or question marks. I was using `Song.new` and setting each value seperately, and the error codes displayed the junk characters as question marks, but after changing to `Song.create( hash )` it displays what is above.

Comment: Axctivrecord complains about `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`, but it obvious that `\xFF\xFE2\x001\x00` is not in `ASCII-8BIT` encoding. So, you can fix this by  converting id3 tags to UTF-8 before calling ActiveRecord.

Comment: @denis.peplin Do you mind giving example code of how to do this, the syntax of string::encode was a bit confusing

Comment: "source string".encoding(dst_encoding, src_encoding). http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode

Comment: @JJD, the comment extracted.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord complains about `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`, but it obvious that `\xFF\xFE2\x001\x00` is not in `ASCII-8BIT` encoding. So, you can fix this by converting id3 tags to UTF-8 before calling ActiveRecord.

```
"source string".encoding(dst_encoding, src_encoding).
```

Documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode